# LibGdx won't load an image

Tags: java, libgdx

I am developing a simple-ish game in LibGdx and when I finally got enough code written to test it, it threw this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: dirt.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at assossa.games.sandbox.blocks.Dirt.<init>(Dirt.java:10)
at assossa.games.sandbox.blocks.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.java:13)
at assossa.games.sandbox.Main.create(Main.java:25)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: dirt.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
... 10 more
```

Here is the code loading the image:

```
new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("dirt.png"))
```

and I have the dirt.png file in core->assets

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the android/assets folder?  It's been a while, but when I used libgdx last that is where the assets had to go.

Comment: I am not developing for android. I only have a core, desktop, and html project.

Comment: Well then I don't know.  I assume that you used the gdx-setup.jar tool.  I just tested it out, the default project has one .png in core/assets and it works.  If I think of anything I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it. Apparently you need to create a assets folder in the desktop project. Then when loading the image, you need to add "assets/" to it. I'm not sure how the default libgdx project works because it does not have a folder in the desktop project.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the correct one by checking it.

Comment: I will, but I can't until tomorrow, sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its in desktop -> assets. Make sure the file is named correctly (no spaces or anything like that). Assuming you set up libgdx correctly, it should work since it will look in that assets folder.

Comment: There is no asset folder in the desktop project. Eclipse shows an asset folder in the desktop project, but its linked to the one in the core folder. Everything is name the same.